Wcf request namespace before attributes name
I am sending WCF request and each request is required to have custom header - attributes with Username and Password must be added to each request.
I've successfully done that with only one exception - I don't know how to add namespace before rendered class name and properties.
It should be like this (rendered xml) - wsse is before attributes names:
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility">
<wsse:Username>test</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">test1</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>

However, adding namespace to DataContract does not render like this, but like this - namespace wsse is not before class name, but inside tag, as attribute - xmlns="wsse". How to make namespace before class name and before attributes name? I am getting 'bad request' error from the server:
<UsernameToken xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
  <Password xmlns="wsse">test1</Password>
  <Username xmlns="wsse">test</Username>
</UsernameToken>

This is what customer wants to be generated - wsse namespace is before UsernameToken and both properties:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cus="http://siebel.com/CustomUI" xmlns:mtel="http://www.siebel.com/xml/Mtel%20Order%20Integration">
             <soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext">
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility">
<wsse:Username>test</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">test</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>

This is how code is generated - before UsernameToken and it's properties is no namespace, it is inside both tags as xmlns="wsse" and I believe this is the reason for error:
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">document/http://siebel.com/CustomUI:UpsertProvisioningStatusData</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:e5896c20-1eec-4171-a4a3-5d5ea52aa75c</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <UsernameToken xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
      <Password xmlns="wsse">test1</Password>
      <Username xmlns="wsse">test</Username>
    </UsernameToken>
  </s:Header>

Class for UsernameToken:
[DataContract(Namespace = "wsse")]
public class UsernameToken
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

And message inspector, where each message gets custom header:
public class MessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger("WS");
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        var property = request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name) ?
        request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] as HttpRequestMessageProperty : new HttpRequestMessageProperty();

        if (null == property)
            return null;

        UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken
        {
            Username = "test",
            Password = "test1"
        };

        request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UsernameToken", "", token));


        return null;
    }
}


You can refer to this link for more help.
